How to do Cloth Simulation in iOS for 3D environment
I would like to do Cloth Simulation in iOS. My idea is to show a curtain with a holder over the window and do Slide In/Out animation based on user action. User can extend the curtain height/width on respective button action.
To do this, I tried multiple ways

Used SceneKit with BallSocketJoints and applied Physical force on it. It doesn't help.
Looked for a soft body module property from Scenekit.
Tried to integrate the Bullet engine. It throws multiple integration issue, which I am trying to fix.
Then, I looked for a wrapper framework PhyKit , It also doesn't include SoftModule wrapper files. 
In which way I can solve my need. Simulation of cloth should be more realistic. Your ideas could be very much appreciated.


You could use a Rigged Geometry and Animate it i.Ex. with Blender. Then you can play it in SceneKit using the SCNAnimationPlayer. I once implemented a Flag simulation loop that way. It worked very well. (A Geometry Morpher could also do the Job, if it is just an opening/closing animation of your curtain)

Thanks for the reply. This is 3D Drapery with pleats, I expect this to animate like a real one. waving effect, folding animation etc. can we achieve all these with Morpher?

the morpher only works good from one state to another. if you want it to wave like a real curtain or a flag in the wind, you should rig it. i.Ex a Plane geometry with like 20 by 20 segments. then rigged the way you want it and add the animations. keep in mind, this can be quite a lot of work (here is an example: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/rigged-curtain-1613635)

Do we have alternative on this?

as you can imagine, a curtain or flag animation is quite complex, the movements are not constantly the same. when it comes to scenekit, it requires something that scenekit can interpret. A morphed or rigged and animated geometry can be interpreted by scenekit. Any other approach requires more flexibility. It might be a possibility to write a geometry shader modifyer or an entire metal shader, to generate the deformation in real-time. But both of this can also become very complex. I will think about it, but no promises.

I found a Shader-Toy Page in which I assume is happening more or less what you are looking for. (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MldXWX) on the right side you can see the code. One would need to translate this code to Metal, and use it along with a SCNProgram applied to your curtain geometry... Pretty tough, but not impossible.
